# RecyclerView row layout collapsing

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I have a row layout, which is a constraint layout.

However, the layout is collapsing on being displayed, as follows:

[image]

here is what it should look like:

[image]

I want the first 3 element to be constrained to the left, and the last 2 to be constrained to the right, with any empty space being in the middle.

Here's my XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/habitEventCommentTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="comment" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/eventTypeTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="Habit Type" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="TYPE:"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/habitEventCommentTextView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.52" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dateTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="date"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="date" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/habitEventThumbnail"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/greyrabbit"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/dateTextView"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/dateTextView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Check if you are using `wrap_content` as the `layout_width` attribute on the `RecyclerView` or on it's parent view.

Comment: @AjilO.   have both set to match_parent

Answer (score 0):

> try this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtComment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/txtType"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:text="comment" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtType"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="TYPE:"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/txtComment"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/eventTypeTextView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/eventTypeTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/habitEventThumbnail"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/txtType"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:text="Habit Type" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/habitEventThumbnail"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/dateTextView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dateTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="date"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="date" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried this, but nothing is properly attached to the right side of the view.

Comment: First thing what exactly you want?  Share image.

Answer (score -1):

use a relative layout with two child linear layout ,one alignparentleft and one alignparent right.

Comment: that doesn't really answer the question of how to fix a constraint layout. And adding child linear layouts would cause a whole suite of problem's that I don;t want to deal with.